# SessionState cookieName to rename Asp.net_Session_ID nulls the session["CaptchaVerify"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies, session-state

I need to use custom name for SessionIdentifier say mySessionID instead of ASP.NET_SessionID. I did it usieng below in WEB.Config:

```
**<sessionState cookieName="drawSessionID" />**
```

But when I am validating the captcha using Session["CaptchaVerify"], it founds out to be null. I am using below html for captcha :

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl = "~/Captcha.aspx"; runat="server" Height="55px" Width="186px" />
```

PS: I need to host this on SSL environment

Kindly help

Comment: how are you setting  and getting `Session["CaptchaVerify"]`, can you show the code?

Comment: Captcha.aspx Page Load : Session["CaptchaVerify"] = captchaText.ToLower();
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                 
Login_Submit_Click:</b> 
      captchaText = Convert.ToString(Session["CaptchaVerify"]).ToLower();